# Echoing fixed number of images on a single row

Tags: php, html, image, echo

How are these images being shown. Are they displaying it by calling the php echo on the set html table or do they just echo it using while loop. The data are taken from the database. and how do they make the 4th image a new row after 3 images are displayed. Beginner here. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: its likely they are floated using CSS style, in a parent container of a set width.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to display data on a web page.  If you want to see what their HTML and CSS is like, take a look at the page source for that site in your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: "Are they displaying it by calling the php echo"...how should we know, do you imagine? We can't see the server-side source code any more than you can. It could all be static hard-coded content for all we can guess. From what you've posted we can't even prove that PHP was ever involved at all, it could be any server language...or none. What you _can_ do is look at the generated HTML and CSS using your browser's tools, so you can at least see how the layout is achieved, even if you don't know what server-side script was used to create it.

Comment: Also, does the site always display exactly three images per row, or does it vary depending on the size of the browser window? That's quite a common feature in modern sites.

Answer (score 0):

The Basic Principle is Keep track of the total number of pictures you add with a variable, say $reconi, and if the modulus (Remainder of Division by 3) is 0, then add a line break (In the example below I am showing Images pulled from a Directory, I already had the script handy, but you shall easily adapt it for doing from database as well). If not clear, feel free to get back.

```
$directory = "D:/ItemPics/";
$files = glob($directory . "*");

$reconi=1;

foreach($files as $file){
  if($reconi % 3==0){     
    // Add picture 
    // Add a line break 
  }else{
    // Add picture;
  }
  $reconi++
}
```

Comment: this assumes the layout in question is in fact fixed. OP provided no info about what happens when the viewport is bigger or smaller. Many modern websites make use of flexible layout schemes to allow content to flow to the width of the viewport, so if there's room to display 5 items in one row, it'll do that, if there's only room for 1, it'll do that instead. That would be achieved using CSS, not PHP

Comment: I have given him the basic idea. He should be knowing how he add the pictures in his layout, whether by floating left, or by some other 1/3 width method. Of course he shall get back, if he could not understand.  Also I have Just said Add line-break. If it is floating way, it should be Adding a clear:both, if he is adding pictures by inline-blocks, just a <br> will do.

Comment: if you read the question, it's not the OP's website. They are asking us to magically guess the server side code of a 3rd party site. P.s. your css suggestions will not really produce a truly responsive site. Fixed line breaks or clearing of floats will, well, fix the layout...

Comment: As I said, you are assuming a fixed layout is truly there, when we don't actually know for sure. And most ppl don't want a fixed layout these days because it's usually going to look terrible on different sizes of screens.